# Classifier 'TelephonyManager' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I saw few answers on SO regarding this but none worked for me.

I am getting this error:

```
 Classifier 'TelephonyManager' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here
```

on the line:

```
val telephoneManager: TelephonyManager = TelephonyManager getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)
```

I am trying to typecaste the variable to `TelephonyManager` and that's where it is giving me this compile-time error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cast is wrong.  You don't case by using the name of the class like that, so it's looking for a function or variable with that name.  Try `val telephoneManager: TelephonyManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager`

In fact the `: TelephonyManager` part is also probably unneeded, but won't hurt to keep.